# how to send images from drawable file to server via retrofit?

Tags: java, android, image, kotlin, mobile

I couldn't find any information about it on the internet

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AddNoteBookFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentAddNoteBookBinding>(FragmentAddNoteBookBinding::inflate) {
    private val viewmodel : MainViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var adapter: AddNoteBookAdapter
    private var imagePath:String=""
    private lateinit var imagePickerLauncher : ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
    override fun onViewCreate() {
        initAdapter()
        observer()
        addNoteResultLauncher()
        binding.saqlash.setOnClickListener {
            if (validation()){
                val filesDir = requireContext().filesDir
                val file = File(filesDir,"image.png")
                val inputStream = requireActivity().contentResolver.openInputStream(imagePath.toUri())
                val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                inputStream!!.copyTo(outputStream)
                val requestbody = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                val part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",file.name,requestbody)
                viewmodel.saveAttachment(part)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun observer() {
        viewmodel.saveAttachment.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){state->
            when(state){
                is BaseNetworkResult.Error -> {
                    toast(state.message)
                    binding.saqlash.show()
                    binding.progressLGG.hide()
                }
                is BaseNetworkResult.Loading -> {
                    binding.progressLGG.show()
                    binding.saqlash.hide()
                }
                is BaseNetworkResult.Success -> {
                    binding.progressLGG.hide()
                    binding.saqlash.show()
                    val data = state.data
                    if (data!=null){
                        viewmodel.addNoteBook(AddNoteBookRequest(
                            name = binding.nomEditText.text.toString(),
                            attachmentId = data.id
                        ))
                    }else{
                        toast("Serverda xatolik yana bir bor urunib ko'ring")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        viewmodel.addNoteBook.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){state->
            when(state){
                is BaseNetworkResult.Error -> {
                    binding.progressLGG.hide()
                    binding.saqlash.show()
                    toast(state.message)
                }
                is BaseNetworkResult.Loading -> {
                    binding.progressLGG.show()
                    binding.saqlash.hide()
                }
                is BaseNetworkResult.Success -> {
                    binding.progressLGG.hide()
                    binding.saqlash.show()
                    toast("Success")
                    navController.navigate(R.id.notebooksFragment)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun validation(): Boolean {
        if (binding.nomEditText.text.toString().length<2){
            YoYo.with(Techniques.Wobble).duration(500).repeat(0).playOn(binding.nomTextInput)
            return false
        }else if (imagePath==""){
            YoYo.with(Techniques.Wobble).duration(500).repeat(0).playOn(binding.list)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    private fun addNoteResultLauncher(){
        imagePickerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {
                try {
                    imagePath = result.data!!.data.toString()
                    Glide.with(this)
                        .load(imagePath)
                        .into(binding.imgUr)
                    binding.imgUr.show()
                } catch (e:Exception){
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
        val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*")
        imagePickerLauncher.launch(galleryIntent)
//        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
//        imagePickerLauncher.launch(intent)
    }
    private fun checkStoragePermissionAndGetImage(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(),
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
        }else{
            pickImageFromGallery()
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == 1){
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                pickImageFromGallery()
            }else{
                toast("Storage permission is denided, please allow permission to get image")
            }
        }
    }
    private fun initAdapter(){
        adapter = AddNoteBookAdapter { position->
            if (position==0){
                checkStoragePermissionAndGetImage()
            }
        }
        val list = ArrayList<Int>()
        list.add(R.drawable.add_notebook_list0)
        list.add(R.drawable.add_notebook_list1)
        list.add(R.drawable.add_notebook_list2)
        list.add(R.drawable.add_notebook_list3)
        list.add(R.drawable.add_notebook_list4)
        list.add(R.drawable.add_notebook_list5)
        list.add(R.drawable.add_notebook_list6)
        list.add(R.drawable.add_notebook_list7)
        list.add(R.drawable.add_notebook_list8)
        adapter.setData(list)
        binding.list.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

[image]

This code shows a plus image on element 0 of the listview. There, if plus is selected, any picture from the gallery will be downloaded and sent to the server. If another element is selected, the image from that element will be sent to the server.

Comment: `I couldn't find any information about it on the internet` ???? About what?